# Multiple ContentProviders in Activity like LEFT JOIN

Tags: android, left-join, android-contentprovider

I am using a `FragmentActivity` to display information from my own `ContentProvider` which is loaded with a `CursorLoader`. That `ContentProvider` delivers a phone number and I would like to have the name and image of that contact if available.

In the first approach I queried the `ContactsContract` in the `CursorAdapter` but that isn't the best solution as it makes the scrolling laggy even on fast devices.

I thought and searched about my problem and created 3 ways:

1. A `left join` with two `ContentProviders` but I found nothing about that.
2. Creating a custom Loader class like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431816/cursorloader-for-multiple-contentproviders).
3. A service wich adds the information from `ContactsContract` to my own `ContentProvider` so I only have to query one provider.

Let's discuss that. :D

Kind Regards,

k.j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that what I was trying was not the best idea.

Now I will use a small `AsyncTask` when I start my app that updates my internal Database with information from `ContactsContract`. With that method I can use my own `ContentProvider` with all needed information in a very simple way. :-)