# Get data from multiple tables using Content Provider

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

Hello everyone,
              I am using content provider and create a database with multiple tables. I already get , insert , update and delete the values of tables. Now I want to get data from multiple tables in a single query. I wounder how can I do it by content provider and cursor. Kindly help me on this. Thanks

Comment: are you familiar with sql joins?

Comment: yes.I am But how to use them in content provider?

Comment: in query method return a Cursor which contains the data from table joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join multiple tables using a ContentProvider.

Look at [android-contentprovider-database-query-multiple-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787548/android-contentprovider-database-query-multiple-tables?rq=1).

So the source code is also available at GitHub,

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_providers_contactsprovider/blob/master/src/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsProvider2.java